# Covered puts and covered calls

Tags: options, covered-call

Why is it not possible to sell covered puts but we can sell covered calls? What happens if I short a stock and short a put?

Comment: When you short a stock, sell (short) a put that is basically a covered put, so you can do it. Who says you can’t?

Answer (score 1):

If you have account approval to sell options and to short stock then you can sell a covered put  as long as you have sufficient margin to support the transaction.

A covered call is synthetically equivalent to a short put.  A covered put is synthetically equivalent to a short call.  In both cases, unless you are legging into the position, it would make no sense to execute two legs (stock and option) when you could execute only one.